# How to load CSV as factor in R

Tags: r

I have a file called metadata.csv that I want to load into R and convert to a factor.
I begin with:

```
metadata <- read.csv(file="metadata.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=T)
```

And this loads the CSV just fine. I've printed out metadata here:

```
> metadata
                   Filename  Genre   Date Gender
1           Austen_Emma.txt Social  Early Female
2           Bronte_Eyre.txt Social Middle Female
3  Dickens_Expectations.txt Social   Late   Male
4            Eliot_Mill.txt Social   Late Female
5            Lewis_Monk.txt Gothic  Early   Male
6     Radcliffe_Italian.txt Gothic  Early Female
7  Shelley_Frankenstein.txt Gothic Middle Female
8        Stoker_Dracula.txt Gothic   Late   Male
9      Thackeray_Vanity.txt Social Middle   Male
10       Trollope_Vicar.txt Social Middle   Male
```

Now I want to convert it to a factor:

```
as.factor(metadata)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Comment: try `do.call( data.frame , lapply( metadata , factor ) )`

Comment: I confess that I'm a little confused as to why you're reading in the file using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and then converting all the columns to factors...?

Comment: That doesn't give me an error. But doesn't seem to give me a factor either. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: stringsAsFactors = TRUE doesn't make any difference. Same error.

Comment: My point was that by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` you had explicitly told R to read all character columns as character, not factors. Using `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` means that they will _already_ be factors. There will be no need to convert them. So your edit to the question makes it read sort of like nonsense.

Comment: @RafaelCosman try `str( metadata )` both when you give `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. See the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`metadata` is a dataframe which is a special type of list made up of vectors of equal length.  You can only use `as.factor()` on vectors.  Therefore you must class `as.factor()` on each vector in the dataframe.  This can be done using the [`lapply`](http://www.howtor.net/introduction/apply) function:

```
metadata <- data.frame(lapply(metadata, factor))
```

This will convert each column to a factor (check this by `class(metadata[, 1])`).  The overall structure of `metadata` will still be a dataframe.

Comment: +1. A more concise approach: `metadata[] <- lapply(metadata, factor)`

Answer (score 2):

`read.csv` puts data into a data.frame

**You cannot convert a `data.frame` into a `factor`.** That's very basic R stuff.

It's like you're trying to change of a bunch of .doc files into PDFs by converting your computer into a PDF. It just doesn't make sense.

The error is asking "Have you called sort on a list?" Yes, you have. `as.factor` calls `sort`, and your `data.frame` is a list.